# Why wouldn't VirtualBox 6 let me resize the virtual screen?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, screenresolution

Virtualbox 6 doesn't let me resize the virtual screen. What could explain this issue?

[image]

The "scale to 100%" stay selected even though I tried to manually select other resolutions.

Using Microsoft Windows 10 as host in Microsoft Windows 7 as guest.

The guest additions are installed:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the guest additions installed? They are required for this to work. Resizing without the guest additions does not affect the guest resolution, since the OS itself must know about the resolution change and there is no mechanism other than guest additions that can deliver this information to the guest OS.

Comment: Thanks, The guest additions are installed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cd7Gz.jpg

Comment: Are they also properly up to date, and is the resizing even enabled?

Also noted the comments on your other answer. You want a resolution higher than the host, that is obviously not a supported configuration and my answer is not in that intention.

Comment: "You want a resolution higher than the host, that is obviously not a supported configuration" I don't think this is obvious because the guest resolution used to be higher than the host resolution until recently. Idk what changed.

Comment: What changed is that you have changed the graphics adapter and Windows remembers resolutions based on the adapter. With the tools it will sync up the same resolution. If you want higher resolutions you just attempt to set it higher (it will work and scale it but, like any such thing, you will lose some of the graphics acceleration support).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to resize is to use the Virtualbox menu
*View > Auto-resize guest display*.

You may then resize the VM to any desired size.

If this doesn't help, try to select for the VM some other Graphics Controller for its
emulated hardware.

Comment: "resize the VM to any desired size" do you mean by changing the window size of the virtualbox window? If so, my host has a low resolution, I want the guest to have a higher resolution than the host.

Comment: Using other Graphics Controllers does allow me to change the resolution, thanks! If anyone knows why, explanation welcome